# filter query results without launching a new sql query

Tags: django

With this code I expected that an sql query would run only on 'all_user_videos' and that the subsequent filter would use the results stored in 'all_user_videos' to do the filter.

```
    # Get all user videos
    all_user_videos = Video.objects.filter( author = user )

    # User pending videos
    pending_videos = all_user_videos.filter( status = 'pending_review' )

    # Get user Video that need information
    info_required_videos = all_user_videos.filter( status = 'info_required' )

    # Get user video on sale
    on_sale_videos = all_user_videos.filter( status = 'on_sale' )

context = {
        "user_member_profile": instance,
        'pending_videos'     : pending_videos,
        'info_required'      : info_required_videos,
        'on_sale'            : on_sale_videos
    }
```

It seems not to be the case, and that each filter runs a query.
How can I make so that pending_videos, info_required_videos and on_sale_videos don't relaunch queries and use result from the query in 'all_user_videos' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex in a query.

```
all_user_videos = list(Video.objects.filter(author=user, status__regex=r'^(pending_review|info_required|on_sale)$'))
pending_videos = [i for i in all_user_videos if i.status == 'pending_review']
```

or

```
pending_videos = []
for i in all_user_videos:
    if i.status == 'pending_review':
        pending_videos.append(i)
    elif i.status == 'info_required':
       ...
```

Comment: it works thank you, but I don't get why you use the regex. It works fine without it... get all the videos from user, and then use the comprehension in each case where needed

Comment: `get all the videos from user,` then this contain also the videos that don't have the status `pending_review|info_required|on_sale`. Regex helps you to reduce somewhat  the all_videos list.